# Reading data from string buffer in Android JAVA code received from Bluetooth

Tags: java, android

I have JAVA code that i receive data using Android App via Bluetooth like the attached code

[image: Java code]

so readMessage will equal = `{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":"temperature"}` from the bluetooth module

so i want to take only the **temperature** value from received data so can any one suggest how to make it

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
 but if the message like this 
                                         
String readMessage = "{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":\"20\"},{\"Pin\":\"A5\",\"Value\":\"925\"},{\"Pin\":\"A0\",\"Value\":\"30\"}"
                                         
how i can extract the String pattern = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to target the value inside the `Value` key:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String readMessage = "{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":\"temperature\"}";
    String pattern = "Value\":\"(.*)\"";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(readMessage);
    m.find();

    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`m.group(1)` holds the value.

Or you can use JSONObject from the [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String readMessage = "{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":\"temperature\"}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readMessage);

    System.out.println(json.getString("Value"));
}
```

#### Output:

```
temperature
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if the message like this String readMessage = "{\"Pin\":\"A4\",\"Value\":\"20\"},{\"Pin\":\"A5\",\"Value\":\"925\"},{\"Pin\":\"A0\",\"Value\":\"30\"}" how i can extract the String pattern = ?

Comment: @IbrahimAbdElRahman Is that the exact raw data you received or did it also have `[` and `]` around them?

Comment: this the exact data i received and i will put this code in Android application so the Bluetooth will receive data in the readMessage and i want to filter on values to display it on android screen